# Use of OCR to read node graphs

Tags: python, nodes, ocr

I would like to code a program that will use a phones camera to read a node graph and then perform dijkstra's algorithm on it, displaying the shortest path.
Could pytesseract or other OCR tools for python read node graphs (such as in the image. Real use would be on printed ones) and give me enough information to get node coordinates and what letters are next to them, as well as the positions of the edges/which nodes they connect and what numbers are next to them?
Any help would be much appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUZwA.jpg

Comment: image recognition is quite involved, this is approximately equivalent to a dissertation amount of work! I'd recommend starting on a smaller project to make a letter recognition program, perhaps a wordsearch reader or something, then from there write a program that attempts to recognise straight lines with a degree of confidence for each potential line, and calibrate. This is quite a broad question though... this is not a software hut! =)